# Batch script stops after first call to other batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm attempting to execute a batch script that currently looks like this:

```
D:
cd D:My Documents\FtpSolution\Test
getftp.bat
call delimconvert.exe
call convert-to-xls.bat
```

However this stops dead after getftp.bat has run.

What am I doing wrong? It's important that these commands all run sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `start` command to launch it in a new window.

`start /wait getftp.bat`

Comment: Does this require 'exit' to be at the end of the other batch scripts? Currently once the first script has finished in the new window it just sits there at the prompt.

Answer (score 37):

Use `call`:

```
Calls one batch program from another.

CALL [drive:][path]filename [batch-parameters]

  batch-parameters   Specifies any command-line information required by the
                     batch program.
```

If you invoke other batch files without `call` then control is passed to them but not back again (which is what `call` changes).

Comment: If the called batch file invokes _another_ batch file, this will not help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "Goto :EOF" rather than "exit" at the end of the batch file that you're calling - in your case, the getftp.bat file...
That's what fixed mine - tested on Win10 enterprise.