# Batch file in windows 7

Tags: batch-file

I have 1st bat file(myFileAll.bat) which has

```
myFile1.bat ../project/MyApp1.exe
myFile1.bat ../project/MyApp2.exe
myFile1.bat ../project/MyApp3.exe
```

myFile1.bat I am passing %1%2%3 as parameters

But only MyApp1.exe is building the rest two are not

Comment: `myFile1.bat ../project/MyApp1.exe ../project/MyApp2.exe ../project/MyApp3.exe`?

Comment: myFile1.bat ../project/MyApp1.pro ../project/MyApp2.pro ../project/MyApp3.pro

Comment: I would use quotes on each side of the arguments as well.  Would help to see your actual batch file to see how you are processing the arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file stops running after the first command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107261)

Comment: per your description you are not passing %1%2%3 you are running the batch three times passing %1.  And Stephan correctly identifies that you are actually only executing the myFile1.bat 1 time because you are not `call` ing it so you never return for subsequent lines to run.

Answer (score 1):

if you just execute a secondary batchfile with it's name, you transfer control to it. If it finishes, you are back at commandprompt.

You have to `call` or `start` it to return control to the primary script:

```
call myFile1.bat ../project/MyApp1.exe
call myFile1.bat parameter1 parameter2 parameter3
call myFile1.bat "Param 1 with spaces" "param two" "param 3"
```